# Loading Data into Custom SalesForce Object using Data Loader

Tags: salesforce, wizard, apex-data-loader

I created a simple object using Schema Builder with two fields.

I was able to load into the custom object using Data Wizard.

But when I use DataLoader, I don't see the object in the list of the Objects, even when I choose "All SalesForce Objects"

Answer (score 1):

If you logged into the DataLoader prior to creating your object, you'll need to logout and login again, while you're at it, make sure you're logging into the correct instance (sandbox vs production).

If you still do not see the object, check the object in Salesforce and make sure it is "Deployed" and not "In Development".

If you still do not see the object, check the CRUD settings on your profile.  You need Create access on the object.

If you still do not see the object, try renaming it.  If the object has the same name as another object, it can be difficult to distinguish.